# Finding most common values in each column

Tags: mysql, max

Below is what I have in table `myTable`.

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   9    |   4    |   3    |   3    |
|   1    |   2    |   9    |   3    |
|   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |
|   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want output as

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

`value1=1` because 1 is thrice in that column.

`value2=2` because 2 is thrice in that column.

`value3=3` because 3 is thrice in that column.

`value4=4` because 4 is twice in that column and that is maximum number of all common number in that column.

**NOTE** : `value4` has most common values as 3 and 4. In output I should get 4 as 4 is the greatest in 3,4.

Can I achieve this in mysql?

### Update 1

### [Table at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3434)

### Update 2

I am listing answer here also so that no need to go on js-fiddle. (as per @ypercube answer)

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT value1
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY value1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value1 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS value1,

  ( SELECT value2
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY value2
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS value2,

  ( SELECT value3
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY value3
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value3 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS value3,

  ( SELECT value4
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY value4
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value4 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS value4
;
```

Comment: And what if there are 2 (or more) values which are most common in some column?

Comment: then show maximum value. I have edited the question.

Comment: @ypercube Increase the Limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT value1
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY value1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value1 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS value1,

  ( SELECT value2
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY value2
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , value2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS value2,
...
  ( SELECT valueN
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY valueN
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           , valueN DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS valueN
;
```

SQL-Fiddle: [test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97226/1)

Comment: can you see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3434) and let me know the solution. Your query is giving me error. Also I have updated my question.

Comment: @FahimParkar: ypercube's query works fine - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97226/1 (your sqlfiddle was set to use MSSQL, not MySQL).

Answer (score -1):

This probably is not an ideal way to store data.
You might want to consider to use key-value pair to normalise 4 columns.
(that's mean one row for each column)

(You can use UNION to achieve what you are looking for)

```
(select value1, null, null, null from TABLE group by value1 order by count(*) desc, value1 desc limit 1)
union
(select null, value2, null, null from TABLE group by value2 order by count(*) desc, value2 desc limit 1)
union
(select null, null, value3, null from TABLE group by value3 order by count(*) desc, value3 desc limit 1)
union
(select null, null, null, value4 from TABLE group by value4 order by count(*) desc, value4 desc limit 1)
```

Comment: That will produce a resultset with four rows, not the one which the OP desires...