# Counting payment types and assigning labels to clients based on most common orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have a large table of orders with 20+ columns. Within this there are ACCOUNT_ID and PAYMENT_TYPE.

I'd like to have three separate tables, based on preferred (most common) payment type.

I can count the payment type for each client easily enough, but have no idea as to the logic behind achieving what I need.

Hoping someone can point me int he right direction?

Please let me know if this is not clear, or an example is needed

Comment: Maybe you can just create 3 different views instead modifying the table .

Comment: Seems you're mixing "database" and "table" (and/or "view") ?

Comment: Sorry - yes I meant 'table' Raphael

Comment: Kira - The issue is I can count the instances of each, but not pick the most frequent and relate this to the client_id?

Comment: oh.. i thought you already know the top 3 payment types.

Comment: @finngeraghty i found this maybe this will help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815268/finding-most-common-values-in-each-column

Comment: Example would be great. Few rows of sample data and expected result on them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted the tables split as different payment types, use views and not separate tables or each time you insert a row into Orders, you need to also insert into the relevant Order[PaymentType] table through some mechanism (manually, trigger etc).

As W3schools puts it:

> In SQL, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL
>   statement.

You define a query that returns a result set, then you can treat that like you would a table. This means as you insert rows into Orders, you can view them in your view if they match the conditions, you do not need to worry about updating another table.

Assuming you wish to split them on payment types, and you had a similar payment type table as the following:

```
PaymentTypeId      PaymentTypeDesc
----------------------------------
1                  Cash
2                  Cheque
3                  Credit Card
```

then the following might be what you're looking for.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersCash AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE = 1

CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersCheque AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE = 2

CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersCreditCard AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE = 3
```

Just treat them as tables to do whatever you wish.

```
SELECT * FROM vw_OrdersCash
```

EDIT:

Reading one of your comments to your question, it sounds like you want it more dynamic than the suggestion above. It's hard to tell without sample output what it is you're trying to achieve, but if you wanted 3 dynamic tables you could extend the above, and rather than the views filtering to a specific payment type, they would filter to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd most common at the time of execution.

An idea of how to do this is below. The lookup view vw_OrdersTopThreePaymentMethods looks at the orders table and returns the top three payment types in descending order of number of orders (ie 1st, 2nd, 3rd). There are then views that will grab all of the orders on that specific type, with all the order information available for you to query as you want.

```
-- A lookup view that returns the top 3 payment methods of orders

CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersTopThreePaymentMethods AS
    SELECT TOP 3 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.OrderCount DESC) AS Row,
        PAYMENT_TYPE, 
        OrderCount 
    FROM (
    SELECT PAYMENT_TYPE , COUNT(*) as 'OrderCount'
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY PAYMENT_TYPE 
    ) a
    ORDER BY a.OrderCount desc

-- 3 views that then get the orders for the top three methods based on output of vw_OrdersTopThreePaymentMethods

CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersPrimaryPayment AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE IN (
    SELECT PAYMENT_TYPE
    FROM vw_OrdersTopThreePaymentMethods
    WHERE Row = 1
)

CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersSecondaryPayment AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE IN (
    SELECT PAYMENT_TYPE
    FROM vw_OrdersTopThreePaymentMethods
    WHERE Row = 2
)

CREATE VIEW vw_OrdersTertiaryPayment AS
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE IN (
    SELECT PAYMENT_TYPE
    FROM vw_OrdersTopThreePaymentMethods
    WHERE Row = 3
)
```